# I have two column paper that I need this equation to fit in

Tags: sharelatex, overleaf

```
\newcommand\PCC{\mathrm{PCC}}
\newcommand\Sim{\mathrm{Sim}}


\begin{equation} 
\begin{align}
\mathit{Sim}_{a,b}^{\mathrm{PCC}} = \frac{%
\sum_{p\in P}( r_{a,p}-\bar{r}_a)(r_{b,p}- \bar{r}_b)} {%
\sqrt{\sum_{p\in P}(r_{a,p}-\bar{r}_a)^2}
\sqrt{\sum_{p\in P}(r_{b,p}-\bar{r}_b)^2}}
\end{align}
\label{Pearson}
\end{equation}
```

The problem is the equation can not be in one column and it changed the font size after this equation

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete small document with your equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose one of these:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\PCC{\mathrm{PCC}}
\newcommand\Sim{\mathrm{Sim}}

\begin{equation} 
\mathit{Sim}_{a,b}^{\mathrm{PCC}} = \frac{%
\sum_{p\in P}( r_{a,p}-\bar{r}_a)(r_{b,p}- \bar{r}_b)} {%
\sqrt{\sum_{p\in P}(r_{a,p}-\bar{r}_a)^2}
\sqrt{\sum_{p\in P}(r_{b,p}-\bar{r}_b)^2}}
\label{Pearson}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} 
\mathit{Sim}_{a,b}^{\mathrm{PCC}} = \frac{%
\sum\limits_{p\in P}( r_{a,p}-\bar{r}_a)(r_{b,p}- \bar{r}_b)} {%
\sqrt{\sum\limits_{p\in P}(r_{a,p}-\bar{r}_a)^2}
\sqrt{\sum\limits_{p\in P}(r_{b,p}-\bar{r}_b)^2}}
\label{Pearson2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} 
\mathit{Sim}_{a,b}^{\mathrm{PCC}} = \frac{%
\sum_{p\in P}AB} {%
\sqrt{\sum_{p\in P}A^2}
\sqrt{\sum_{p\in P}B^2}}
\label{Pearson3}
\end{equation}

where $A=r_{a,p}-\bar{r}_a$ and $B=r_{b,p}- \bar{r}_b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might work, but it depends on the actual width of the column.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newcommand\PCC{\mathrm{PCC}}
\newcommand\Sim{\mathrm{Sim}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}\label{Pearson}
\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
\mathit{Sim}_{a,b}^{\mathrm{PCC}} =
\frac{%
  \sum\limits_{p\in P}( r_{a,p}-\bar{r}_a)(r_{b,p}- \bar{r}_b)} {%
\sqrt{\sum\limits_{p\in P}(r_{a,p}-\bar{r}_a)^2}
\sqrt{\sum\limits_{p\in P}(r_{b,p}-\bar{r}_b)^2}}
\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

The trick of adding large, but shrinkable, space allows the equation to start at the left margin. Using `\sum\limits` we save some horizontal space at the expense of vertical size.

Don't nest `align` inside `equation`.

[image]